# Some functions don't work in portrait layout

Tags: jquery, onload

I need to resize an image depending on browser window size

```
window.onload = function(){

var x = $(window).innerWidth();
var y = $(window).innerHeight();

if (x > y) { land(); }
else { port(); }

function land() {
    $('#slide').css('width', x/2);  // works
    //all other lines here work
};
```

Then I resize Firefox window to portrait layout, cleared the cache and reload the page (F5)

```
function port() {
    alert (x);  // works correctly
    $('#slide').css('width', x/2);  // doesn't work
        //many other lines here don't work
    };
}
```

Comment: no need for a ; at the end of your else IE else { port(); }; can just be else { port(); }

Comment: @abc123, thanks, I corrected this. Main problem remains

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @KhanhTO, I provided a fiddle at `http://jsfiddle.net/Bonaca/zhjbs/` and it works normally. Could you please check this on my site `http://zokam.22web.org/alegro.php`. Resize the window on portrait and reload the page. Alert is there, but the image is not resized.

Comment: @SunSky: img is inline element, it seems that we cannot set width for inline elements, Try adding `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to it

Comment: @KhanhTO, in that case resizing in landscape mode should not work. Also jsfiddle. I tried now to make the image invisible `display:none` in css and show it in jquery. Interesting, in portrait mode, after reloading - it is not hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the img is resized correcty. The problem in your case is the `#ulBack`. The `#ulBack` hides your img in portrait mode because you don't apply `display:none` to it.

You have a css file for each display mode:

```
<link href="css/gallery_port.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation:portrait)"/>
<link href="css/gallery_land.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation:landscape)"/>
```

You apply `display:none` to `#ulBack` in `gallery_land.css` but not in `gallery_port.css`. I tested it by removing the `display:none` in `gallery_land.css` and I got the same problem in `landscape` mode.

Comment: @SunSky: you're wellcome. glad to be able to help